# How to create a deep copy in Karate

Tags: karate, intuit-partner-platform

How can I create a totally independent copy of a variable in karate. So that changing one doesn't affect the other.
I tried simply assigning it to a new variable but it didn't work.

```
* def copyJson = originalJson
```

Changing copyJson changes the originalJson too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, and explained in the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#copy

```
* def original = { key: 'value' }
# this will create a "deep copy"
* copy foo = original
```